# How to get rid of 'Simulator in use' error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I know this question has been asked many times but i didn't find a proper solution to get rid of this error **without quiting** Xcode and start again. Most of the time i prefer working on real device but there are always some cases which i need to work on simulator also.

Is it really possible to get rid of this error without restarting Xcode?

I would appreciate any comments.

Comment: Have you got more than one xcode project open? Maybe one of those is still using the simulator

Comment: Try hitting the stop button in Project 1 and then hit the run button in Project 2.

Comment: there is only one project open @LucaD but this thing happens though

Comment: stopping and running again does not change anything @Zane Helton

Comment: Have you tried just restarting the simulator and not Xcode?

Comment: It's a bug. If you don't like it, file a bug report with Apple. Meanwhile, if you encounter it, you'll just have to keep using the workaround you've already mentioned: quit Xcode (and in fact, perhaps restart the computer itself) to reset everything.